# What is a cusp neighborhood corresponding to a parabolic Möbius transformation in a Riemann surface?

Tags: definition, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I am referring to [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_neighborhood).

So what I understand is that they are defining it using the Fuchsian model. If $\Gamma$ is a Fuchsian group, its parabolic elements correspond to the cusps of $\mathbb{H} / \Gamma$. I do not know why, or what a cusp mathematically is, but I have seen pictures.

Then there is the statement in the WP entry about $\gamma(U) \cap U = \emptyset$. This does not make sense. What if $\gamma$ were a (rational) rotation around $i$? Wouldn't $\gamma(U) \cap U \neq \emptyset$ in that case?

Comment: It's a very badly written Wikipedia entry. I suggest instead looking at a textbook on Riemann surfaces.

Comment: @LeeMosher could you recommend a specific book and/or try to give a short summary?